# Not returning elapsed time in milliseconds

Tags: c#, winforms

I've built this simple stopwatch program to measure time in the format of: 00:00:000 [minutes:seconds:milliseconds], but the code ignores the format and counts up like this: 00:00:[seconds here][milliseconds here], so as a result I can only get the elapsed time in 10s of milliseconds and not the individual millisecond.

Here's the display:

[image]

The actual time elapsed is 3 seconds and 610 milliseconds.

Code:

```
namespace stopwatch_1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        int timeMinutes, timeSeconds, timeMSeconds;
        bool timerActive;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resetTime();
        }

        private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timerActive = true;

        }

        private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timerActive = false;
        }

        private void buttonReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           resetTime();
        }

        private void resetTime()
        {
            timerActive = false;
            timeMinutes = 0;
            timeSeconds = 0;
            timeMSeconds = 0;
        }

        private void timerStopwatch_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (timerActive == true)
            {
                timeMSeconds++;

                if (timeMSeconds >= 1000)
                {
                    timeMSeconds = 0;
                    timeSeconds++;

                    if (timeSeconds >= 60)
                    {
                        timeSeconds = 0;
                        timeMinutes++;

                    }

                }

            }


            timerDraw();

        }

        private void timerDraw()
        {
            labelMinutes.Text = String.Format("{0:00}", timeMinutes);
            labelSeconds.Text = String.Format("{0:00}", timeSeconds);
            labelMSeconds.Text = String.Format("{0:000}", timeMSeconds);

        }


    }
}`
```

The timer interval is set to one, and I've double checked that all variables are pointing to the right labels so I think the problem lies with where I've formatted the string to display, but I'm not sure where I've gone wrong:

```
 private void timerDraw()
    {
        labelMinutes.Text = String.Format("{0:00}", timeMinutes);
        labelSeconds.Text = String.Format("{0:00}", timeSeconds);
        labelMSeconds.Text = String.Format("{0:000}", timeMSeconds);

    }
```

I don't really know how to use string.format in this context, so this is probably where I've gone wrong, all help would be appreciated

Comment: As a rule, please post your code, not a pastebin link to your code. What are those three `time*` variables?

Comment: Firstly, don't use a timer to actually count the time incrementing - they are not reliable enough for that. Instead, store the time you started the timer (`DateTime start = DateTime.Now`) and then whenever your timer fires, simply calculate how long it's been (`TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Now.Subtract(start)`).

Comment: The `TimeSpan` structure has properties like [Seconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.seconds(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Milliseconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.seconds(v=vs.110).aspx) so it's trivial to find out the values you need to print out.

Comment: Ironically, the code you posted to actually output the values looks fine!!

Answer (score 3):

> The Windows Forms Timer component is single-threaded, and **is limited to an accuracy of 55 milliseconds**.

You should use a `Stopwatch` to get a more accurate resolution:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do nothing
}

private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    stopwatch.Start();
}
private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    stopwatch.Stop();
}
private void buttonReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    stopwatch.Reset();
}

private void timerStopwatch_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timerDraw();
}
private void timerDraw()
{
    labelMinutes.Text = String.Format("{0:00}", stopwatch.Elapsed.Minutes);
    labelSeconds.Text = String.Format("{0:00}", stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds);
    labelMSeconds.Text = String.Format("{0:000}", stopwatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds);
}
```

EDIT:

You should also reduce the `Interval` on your timer, since there is no need to `refresh` the labels on a `1ms` interval anymore.

Comment: This! Use a stopwatch - can't believe I forgot about that class!